# Conversion from string "Name" to type 'Integer' is not valid when writing to text file

Tags: vb.net, streamwriter

I've spent about an hour on this problem and can't find a solution.  The error is on the line:
sw.Write(.Item("Name").ToString & ",")

The Name field is a String datatype.

```
If File.Exists(fileSavePath) Then
    Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(fileSavePath, False)
        'Write Column Headers
        sw.Write("Name" & "," & "Unit Number" & "," & "Sunday" & "," & "Monday" & "," & "Tuesday" & "," & "Wednesday" & "," & "Thursday" & "," & "Friday" & "," & "Saturday")
        sw.WriteLine()

        'Write Attendance Information
        For i As Integer = 0 To ScoutDataSet.Tables("AllClasses").Rows.Count - 1
            If ScoutDataSet.Tables("AllClasses").Rows(i).Item("UnitNumber").ToString = troopNumber Then
                With ScoutDataSet.Tables("AllClasses").Rows
                    sw.Write(.Item("Name").ToString & ",")              'Write Name

                    sw.Write(.Item("UnitNumber").ToString & ",")        'Write Unit Number

                    sw.WriteLine() ' Go to next scout
                End With
            End If
        Next
    End Using
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `With` statement is for `ScoutDataSet.Tables("AllClasses").Rows` - i.e. the collection of rows, so `.Item` on that collection is expecting the row index.  Instead you want `With ScoutDataSet.Tables("AllClasses").Rows(i)`:

```
'Write Attendance Information
For i As Integer = 0 To ScoutDataSet.Tables("AllClasses").Rows.Count - 1
    If ScoutDataSet.Tables("AllClasses").Rows(i).Item("UnitNumber").ToString = troopNumber Then
        With ScoutDataSet.Tables("AllClasses").Rows(i)
            sw.Write(.Item("Name").ToString & ",")              'Write Name
            sw.Write(.Item("UnitNumber").ToString & ",")        'Write Unit Number
            sw.WriteLine() ' Go to next scout
        End With
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Sometimes you just need another pair of eyes.  Thanks so much.